# Tangents and Normals of rectangular hyperbolas

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, plane-geometry

Please, could someone explain the solution to **(d)**

[image: question statement]

I solved **(a)**, **(b)** and **(c)** however, I don't understand how to calculate **(d)**.

**(a)** displayed in the question
**(b)** $ q^2 y + x = 10q $
**(c)** displayed in the question
**(d)** ?

I'm not sure what $p^2 q^2$ even infers.

P.s. this is just personal/curiosity study, not, homework or classwork etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth of matter is that we're not actually told what to do, nor is there a method to be sure of what to do -- at all. I'm sure that even the publisher would state that "doing this and that" will **hopefully** give us the correct solution to whatever $p^2 q^2$ is. A.k.a, telepathy dependent questions. The equation determines the *foci* i presume - maybe even the eccentricity.

Here goes;

1. Calculate the gradient of PQ...

$$=\left(\frac{\frac{5}{p}-\frac{5}{q}}{5p-5q}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{\frac{5q}{pq}-\frac{5p}{pq}}{5p-5q}\right)$$
$$\left(\frac{\frac{b}{c}}{a}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{(c).(a)}\right)=\left(\frac{5q-5p}{pq(5p-5q)}\right)$$ 
$$=\left(\frac{-(5p-5q)}{pq(5p-5q)}\right)$$

- $(5p-5q)$ is a common factor so it cancels to;
  $$-\frac{1}{pq}$$

---

2. Calculate the gradient of ON...

$$=\left(\frac{\frac{10}{p+q}-0} {\frac{10pq}{p+q}-0}\right)$$

- "**10**" and "**p+q**" both cancel out due to the expressions being common factor across the top and bottom side of the fraction.

$$\frac{1}{pq}$$

---

3. Multiply the two gradients to solve...

$$\left(-\frac{1}{pq}\right).\left(\frac{1}{pq}\right)$$

$$=-\frac{1}{p^2 q^2}$$

- When the two lines intersect in a specific manner such that they create 4, 90° angles and hence, are known as perpendicular. As a result to this, we know that the product of the multiplication is "equal to", **-1**. i.e. $m_1 m_2 = -1$.
  (only applicable when the gradients in context are of 2 perpendicular lines)

Therefore;

$$-\frac{1}{p^2 q^2} = -1$$

---

4. Rearrange and simplify...

$$-1 = -1(p^2 q^2)$$
$$1 = p^2 q^2$$

---

5. Final answer...

$$p^2 q^2 = 1$$

---

6. End note...

$p=\sqrt{\frac{1}{q^2}}$ or $p=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{q^2}}$

$q=\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^2}}$ or $q=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{p^2}}$

---

p.s. yes, i solved my own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the slope of line $ON$ from point (c) and the slope of line $PQ$: since those two lines are perpendicular, the product of their slopes must be $-1$. From that you get $p^2q^2=1$.

Comment: I'm not following. Where did (4), come from?  I understand the product rule, i just don't truly understand why it's it's relevant to be honest. Unless,  $p^2 q^2$ is referring to the coordinate sets $P$ and $Q$? (One is capitalised and the other is not etc).

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly thought (4) was the number of the formula for $N$ at point (c). Letters $p$ and $q$ refer to the parameters appearing in the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: I think the text would be much clearer if it were stated as "If the line joining $N$ to the origin is perpendicular to line $PQ$, then find the value of $p^2q^2$.

Comment: I'll edit the question now :) Thank you for your help, also.